# SQLite database UTF-8

Tags: android, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I am using a sqlite database and I wrote the data in it manually so the data is not utf-8 encoded and i am writing arabic words..
I inserted a data in arabic (ex: هاهاهاه) into it fro android I got UTF-8 value(ظ‡ط§ظ‡ط§ظ‡ط§ط§ظ‡ط§) and when i converted this utf-8 value to ANSI or windows 1252 using notepad I got the arabic initial value;
So what I want to ask is if I need to use a pre-made database(a database that I won't fill from android but from outside android and link it to android) but I need to insert the arabic values as utf-8 so that I get them in the app or else I am gonna get question marks instead of arabic letters, how can I do that? and am I supposed not to view the real data in sqlite because it will be encoded in utf-8...

And is there a way to convert a database from ansi to utf-8?

please I really need help in this...thanks;

Comment: SQLite database are always assumed to be UTF-8 encoded, and SQLite never changes strings. Just write the data as UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: @CL yeah that's what I did it seems that there is no other solution.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should Place the data encoded in utf-8 in the database, I could do it with notepad++ by using the encoding there...